Different clipboard contents for multiline strings in Excel cell vs. Notepad
This question is related to the familiar issue of copying multiline strings out of Excel cells [1, 2].
I used this solution (64 bit version in the comments) to create a Macro that edits the clipboard contents to remove the quotation marks. This works fine when pasting the string into Word or Notepad; however, the intended application is pasting the string into the property table of a Solidworks part file. This doesn't work: it generates the four entries into the table, but the properties cannot be saved. Pasting the string into Notepad, copying it from there and pasting it into Solidworks does work, despite there being exactly 0 differences detectable to the human eye.
The strings all have the same general format:
    ITEM_ID Text    KAX-02000060-V1 KAX-02000060-V1 0
    PART_NAME   Text    Vertical Stabilizer Fwd Spar Stamp  Vertical Stabilizer Fwd Spar Stamp  0
    PART_NO Text    ZV-056-55-30-01101  ZV-056-55-30-01101  0
    PART_VERSION    Text            0

I inspected the clipboard contents when copying strings out of Excel with the Macro vs. copying the same string out of Notepad. There are some minor differences:

These are the clipboard contents for the macro out of Excel.
These are the clipboard contents for copying the exact same string out of Notepad.

As you can see, there appears to be an extra period character at every line break for the Notepad version. I don't really know how to interpret this or why it can affect how Solidworks reacts to the data and I'd appreciate any insight on the matter.

Yes the starting point is understanding that not all CSV are the same link.  As far as direct conversion (via macro) vs using an intermediary program (Notepad), I can only guess that the format out of excel is just using a CR whereas Stoneworks wants to accept CR/LF (your one period vs two). Update your macro for that and let us know if that solved the problem.
